# Help me with this boolean algebra expression pls

Tags: logic

Can someone explain me why: (!a)*c + ab + bc is equal to (!a)*c + ab ?
Of course by doing the Karnaugh map I've figured it out, but how could I've done just with the boolean laws?

Comment: Have you tried a truth table?

Comment: Do you mean Boolean algbera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution using Boolean Laws:

$$\begin{aligned} \bar{a}c + ab+bc &= \bar{a}c + ab+bc(a+\bar{a}) \\                  &= \bar{a}c + \bar{a}cb + ab+abc \\ &= \bar{a}c(1+b) + ab(1+c) \\                 &= \bar{a}c + ab
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank You! this was very helpful! I'd never thought of that!

Comment: Also, I've just found out this is exactly the demonstration of the Consensus Theorem